# Javascript K Closest Points to Origin in Linear Time?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

Is it problem to solve this problem in linear time O(N)? The only way I see to solve it is with sort() which give me O(NlogN) time.

Problem:
We have a list of points on the plane.  Find the K closest points to the origin (0, 0).

(Here, the distance between two points on a plane is the Euclidean distance.)

You may return the answer in any order.  The answer is guaranteed to be unique (except for the order that it is in.)

My solution:

```
/*
    d = sqrt ( (x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 )
*/

var kClosest = function(points, K) {
    points.sort((a,b) => {
        const d1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a[0], 2) + Math.pow(a[1], 2));
        const d2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b[0], 2) + Math.pow(b[1], 2));
        return d1-d2;
    });
    return points.splice(0, K);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way, using count sort instead.

Suppousing that the maximum X and Y coordinates are fairly limited, you can skip using `Math.sqrt` altogether. You will end up with a `distances` array of integer values representing the square of each point's distance to the center.

Then, you loop from 0 to `the maximum possible distance` through this array and print every point you find, until you have found `K` points.

Here's my implementation (you might be able to make it prettier ):

```
points = [[-1, 9], [2, 2], [10, 15], [3, 4], [7,5]]

var kClosest = function(points, K) {
    const MAX_X = 100
    const MAX_Y = 100
    const MAX_DISTANCE = MAX_X**2 + MAX_Y**2

    let distancesSquared = new Array(MAX_DISTANCE).fill(null).map(() => [])
    for(let point of points) {
        const distanceSquared = point[0]**2 + point[1]**2
        distancesSquared[distanceSquared].push(point)
    }

    const result = []
    let pointsLeft = Math.min(points.length, K) // Make sure K isn't greater than the amount of points
    for(let crtDistance = 0; crtDistance <= MAX_DISTANCE; ++crtDistance) {
        while(distancesSquared[crtDistance].length > 0 && pointsLeft > 0) {
            result.push(distancesSquared[crtDistance].pop())
            --pointsLeft
        }

        if(pointsLeft === 0) { // Tiny optimisation
            break 
        }
    }

    return result
};

kClosest(points, 3)
```

Comment: You are assuming that we won't have points greater than [100,100]. Also ins't your while inside your for loop making it O(N^2) time complexity?

Comment: Yes, by `fairly limited` I meant that the points are somewhere in the range ([-50; 50], [-50; 50]). The first for-loop can be considered O(1) in this circumstance; the while loop, at worst, loops over O(N) items - thus, the algorithm's complexity is roughly O(N) in this particular case. So, yes, sometimes the problem is solvable in O(N). 

Comment: I think when we use Big O notation, we always consider the worst case scenario

Comment: Yes, depending on your problem's constraints. In this case, it will always be O(N).